# Page attributes with PHP and XML

Tags: php, xml, include

Ok so i'd imagine this would be possible to do, but it's a little above my ability. What I have is a basic header.php, index.php, and footer.php that will work with includes. so a sub page would be say about.php and include the header and footer. What i'd like to do is create an xml file that houses all the page info like, parent pages, titles, description, etc. and have a function that gets the current file name, runs the function and returns the relevant data. I have a function that gets the file name...

```
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
$filename = ( $parts[count($parts) - 1]);
```

This function works great and would return the current page file name, for instance about.php. I'd like a function that will send this title to said function, parse the xml for the appropriate content and feed it back. is this even possible?

example xml...

```
<SITE>

<PAGE>
<FILENAME>about.php</FILENAME>
<DESCRIPTION>description description description </DESCRIPTION>
<TITLE>About Us</TITLE>
<PARENTS>
 <PARENT>Company</PARENT>
 <PARENT>People</PARENT>
</PARENTS>
</PAGE>

<PAGE>
<FILENAME>people.php</FILENAME>
<DESCRIPTION>description description description </DESCRIPTION>
<TITLE>People</TITLE>
<PARENTS>
 <PARENT>Company</PARENT>
</PARENTS>
</PAGE>

</SITE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. Here are some general steps:

1. Read in your settings.xml file into a var ie somethimg like file_get_contents.
2. Use: xml_parse_into_struc http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php
3. Navigate that resulting object and then put your items where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being...

This is at the top of dynamic page...

```
include "includes/sitestructure.php";
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
$pagePath = $parts[count($parts) - 1];

$siteInf = getPage($pagePath); 
$description = $siteInf->DESCRIPTION;
$title = $siteInf->TITLE;
```

I basically take the name of the current template file then send it through the getPage function and reference it to the XML in the function seen here...

```
function getPage($pagePath){

$file = "includes/sitestructure.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);  
$pages = $xml->xpath('PAGE[FILENAME="'.$pagePath.'"]');
$pages = $pages[0];

return $pages;  
}
```

then lastly I call my variables in the appropriate place...

```
 <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description ?>">
```